# create menu with baseURL in front of link (absolute links)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typolink

When I create my menu I only have relative paths for the different menu links. How do I get an absolute URL (i.e. a typolink with the baseURL in front of it).

I can think of either defining a variable or write the domain name in the wrap. E.g.

```
10.wrap = <option value="http://www.domain.com/|">
```

But are there better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `config.absRefPrefix = http://www.yourdomain.com/sub/path/`. That will prefix *any* properly generated site-root relative links with the domain.

There may be an alternative way using domain records (Linking across domains in multidomain-sites does exactly what you want), but I can't point you to anything there.

Comment: It seems to work (I had to adapt a script which put the baseURL in front so I had two times the baseURL). While searching I stumbled on this multidomain-site thing but I don't need it here.

Comment: The extention `mc_googlesitemap` creates incorrect links when using `config.absRefPrefix`. So I removed the line and I used a variable for my special case as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the typolink parameter `forceAbsoluteUrl` of the links in your HMENU construct: http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/typolink

Comment: I think that's the cleanest way for that purpose. So related to the question this should be the accepted answer. Anyway I needed absolute URL's on whole page for page is used as Email - so for that the answere from Jost is more practical in my case.